# How do I get the stats of all the pillars on the Zenon Network?

Tags: blockchain, zenon-network

Is there an easy way to get all the statistics on the pillars on the Zenon Network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl on the command line and access the method: embedded.pillar.getAll (https://testnet.znn.space/#!api.md)

I passed the output to the command **jq** so it can be easily read.

> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:35997    -H 'Content-Type:
> application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 20, "method":
> "embedded.pillar.getAll","params": [0, 299]}' | jq

This will give you the output of:

[image]